# Asserting Run Time From Big O Function

Tags: asymptotics, complexity-classes, quantum-computing

Related to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77681/general-number-field-sieve-big-o-clarification), but I felt it was more appropriate to ask as a separate question:

The complexity of Shor's algorithm is of order

$$O\left(n^2\,\log(n)\,\log(\log(n))\right)$$

with $n$ the bit length of the number to be factored. [This paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1134/S1063739711040032) asserts that on a terahertz range quantum computer (i.e. $10^6$ instructions per second) a thousand digit decimal number will take 84 seconds to factorize. It makes this assertion based on taking $\log$ to be $\ln$. By changing the $\log$ base it's obviously possible to get quite different answers e.g. $\log_2$ gives a result of 460 seconds.

My question is, is it at all meaningful/correct make such precise assertions as to run time based on this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base of logarithms is irrelevant in big-O notation, since
$$\log_b x = \frac{\log_a x}{\log_a b} = O(\log_a x)\,,$$
so $O(\log_a x)$ and $O(\log_b x)$ denote exactly the same class of functions.

The assertions made by the paper about how long a certain computer would take to solve some problem don't appear to be well founded.  As a minor issue, doesn't "terahertz range computer" mean $10^{12}$ operations per second, not one million per second?  But the major point is that $O(n^2\log n\log\log n)$ is not the same thing as $n^2\log n\log\log n$: it's merely a statement that, there's some constant $c$ such that, for large enough $n$, the number of computation steps is at most $cn^2\log n\log\log n$.  In particular, it doesn't tell us what the value of $c$ is: it could be $10^{-100}$ or $10^{100}$ or anything else. Further, the analysis is never sufficiently precise to equate some number of "computation steps" with an actual number of machine instructions.

You simply cannot turn an asymptotic expression such as this into a running time in seconds without more information.  One possible way to obtain the value of $c$ would be to time the actual execution of the program, but this isn't possible as we don't have any quantum computers that can run Shor's algorithm on $1000$-digit numbers. I don't see anything that would enable the authors of the paper to give precise wall-clock running times for a program on a computer that doesn't exist.

It appears that the authors are using $\ln$ to denote base-$2$ logarithms, since they say that a $k$-digit number equates to $k\ln10$ bits.  A  1000-digit number is about 3300 bits and
$$3300^2\log_2 3300\log_2\log_2 3300\approx 451\times 10^6\,,$$
so that's certainly not where the $84$-second claim comes from.

It seems, in fact, to come from interpreting $\ln$ as meaning the natural logarithm. Based on the incorrect claim that a $1000$-digit number has $1000\log_e 10\approx 2300$ bits, we get
$$2300^2\log_e 2300\log_e\log_e2300\approx 84\times 10^6\,.$$
This calculation is not meaningful in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response; it's been really helpful! Yeah, I was also confused by the bit length conversion using ln, but this does seem to be where they got the 84 seconds from [edit: this site is screwing up the URL], but if you enter (1000*\ln(10))^2\,\ln(1000*\ln(10))\,\ln(\ln(1000*\ln(10))) on http://www.wolframalpha.com/ it returns the result in the paper. I guess I shouldn't pay too much attention to this paper anyway based on your answer (also pointing out the terahertz error) so it doesn't really matter how they've come to this.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can't predict the concrete running time based on an asymptotic expression for the running time, as asymptotic analysis ignores constant factors.  You don't know whether the big-O notation hides a factor of 3 or 3 million.

Comment: Thanks. David has given a more detailed answer saying essentially the same so I've marked his as accepted, but your answer's appreciated.